# Error with PHPass on authentification

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using PHPass for password encryption and for authenticating login.

When I try login, it gives errors:_

Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: invalid object or resource C:\mysqli rootfile-blahblahblah\includes\user.php on line 41

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\rootfile-blahblahblah\includes\user.php on line 43

I followed the manual for authentication but it's ont working for some reason.

Heres the code of the authentication function

```
   public static function authenticate($username, $password)
{
    $pwdhasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
    $hashed_pwd = $pwdhasher->HashPassword($password);

    $db = new mysqli();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT hashed_password FROM users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1");
    if (!$stmt) die($db->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_pwd);


if ($pwdhasher->CheckPassword($password, $hashed_pwd)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
unset($pwdhasher);

}
```

And for the login.php page where it runs the function:_

```
$username = $database->escape_value(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = $database->escape_value(trim($_POST['password']));

    $user = User::find_by_id(1);
    $found_user = User::authenticate($username, $password);

    if ($found_user)
    {
        $session->login($found_user, $user);
        $message = "You have Logged in.";
        redirect_to("index.php");
    }
    else { $message = "Incorrect username/password."; }

}
```

I've searched alot and tried alot of things, but to no avail. :/

Now you see, what I want is it to check the username and hashed password which are in the database and login if they are correct, I know how to checkPassword() and encrypt it with HashPassword, but I can't find how to make it authenticate username and password....

Comment: Looks like a problem in using and connecting MySQLi, nothing to do with phpass.